# Beta Graph API eDiscovery Review Set Apply Tag appear to be tagging just the Group/Section tag and not the child tag

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate, o365security-compliance

I'm am developing a power automate flow using the Beta Advanced eDiscovery Graph API which I do the following:

1. Create a Tag structure for an Advanced eDiscovery Case. This consists of a Section/Group (Parent) Tag named 'Privilege' the 4 child Tags. (see code below) All functions are working w/o error and appear in the eDisovery Case.
2. Using the Beta Graph API I create a Review Set Query. (see code below) This too is working w/o errors and appears in the eDiscovery Case Review.
3. Lastly, Using the Beta Graph API I apply one of the child tags associated to the review query from step 2. Again this works w/o error.

The issue is that when I open the Review in Advanced eDiscovery I see the messages that match the review query matches on with Tags, however when I view the message the child tag does not get highlighted.

If I apply a tag manually then again view the message the Tag is highlighted (selected).

Also, when in the Review Set page tag Filter only lists the Parent Tag not the child tag which I specified in the applytag Graph Apl call.

Following are Graph API calls, URI, Body, and Outputs:

Make the Group Tag

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b/tags

Body

{
"displayName": "Privilege",
"childSelectability": "Many"
}

Output

```
{
    "@odata.context": "graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#compliance/ediscovery/cases('9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b')/tags/$entity",
  "displayName": "Privilege",
  "description": null,
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-06T21:13:59.6518126Z",
  "childSelectability": "Many",
  **"id": "4ab4daccb8c14ef789be7d2580bab245",**
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "displayName": null,
      "userPrincipalName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Make 4 child options

```
1.
```

POST //graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b/tags

Body

```
{
  "displayName": "Attorney Work Product",
  "childSelectability": "Many",
  "parent@odata.bind": "//graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b/tags/**4ab4daccb8c14ef789be7d2580bab245**"
}
```

Outputs
Status Code:201

```
{
  "@odata.context": "://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#compliance/ediscovery/cases('9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b')/tags/$entity",
  "displayName": "Attorney Work Product",
  "description": null,
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-06T21:14:00.2924266Z",
  "childSelectability": "Many",
  "id": "6646aa1cde37408dad6be43723dd0503",
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "displayName": null,
      "userPrincipalName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  }
}
```

2.POST
//graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b/tags
Body

```
{
  "displayName": "Attorney Communication",
  "childSelectability": "Many",
  "parent@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b/tags/4ab4daccb8c14ef789be7d2580bab245"
}
```

Outputs

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#compliance/ediscovery/cases('9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b')/tags/$entity",
  "displayName": "Attorney Communication",
  "description": null,
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-06T21:14:01.1385531Z",
  "childSelectability": "Many",
  "id": "03a1f53540874e7085dc57bdb6e71b29",
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "displayName": null,
      "userPrincipalName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  }
}

3. POST
```

//graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b/tags

Body

```
{
  "displayName": "Potentially Privileged",
  "childSelectability": "Many",
  "parent@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b/tags/4ab4daccb8c14ef789be7d2580bab245"
}
```

Outputs

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#compliance/ediscovery/cases('9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b')/tags/$entity",
  "displayName": "Potentially Privileged",
  "description": null,
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-06T21:14:01.5424902Z",
  "childSelectability": "Many",
  "id": "dee7b721d042423a870f9fd695cff573",
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "displayName": null,
      "userPrincipalName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  }
}

4. Post
```

://graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b/tags

body

```
{
  "displayName": "Privileged",
  "childSelectability": "Many",
  "parent@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b/tags/4ab4daccb8c14ef789be7d2580bab245"
}
```

Outputs

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#compliance/ediscovery/cases('9bb82c7c-bba3-4ad2-a584-4ec30a33544b')/tags/$entity",
  "displayName": "Privileged",
  "description": null,
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-06T21:14:02.0233516Z",
  "childSelectability": "Many",
  "id": "2bb05d142ab7455eb16a820a54f147fb",
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "displayName": null,
      "userPrincipalName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBL05.png)

Make Review Set Query
//graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/f193df40-551d-451c-9ef8-135df2475fc2/reviewSets/921d10fa-9a16-44e5-8240-d9f9cb7d1b5f/queries

Body

```
{
  "displayName": "Potentially Privileged",
  "query": "(SenderAuthor:\"adeleV@pageman.onmicrosoft.com\" OR Recipients:\"adeleV@xxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com\")"
}
```

Outputs
Status code 201

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#compliance/ediscovery/cases('f193df40-551d-451c-9ef8-135df2475fc2')/reviewSets('921d10fa-9a16-44e5-8240-d9f9cb7d1b5f')/queries/$entity",
  "displayName": "Potentially Privileged",
  "query": "((SenderAuthor:\"adeleV@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com\" OR Recipients:\"adeleV@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com\"))",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T21:37:38.4273704Z",
  "id": "1c2670a8-7542-4168-9873-b62b3d097cc5",
  "createdDateTime": "2021-11-11T21:37:38.4273704Z",
  "lastModifiedBy": {
    "user": {
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "displayName": null,
      "userPrincipalName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  },
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "displayName": null,
      "userPrincipalName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Apply Tag
//graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases/f193df40-551d-451c-9ef8-135df2475fc2/reviewSets/921d10fa-9a16-44e5-8240-d9f9cb7d1b5f/queries/1c2670a8-7542-4168-9873-b62b3d097cc5/applyTags

Body

```
{
  "tagsToAdd": [
    {
      "id": "e4518b76afec491b8d845f87179791f3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Outputs
Status Code 202

Using the location I track the progress until 100% complete

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#compliance/ediscovery/cases('f193df40-551d-451c-9ef8-135df2475fc2')/operations/$entity",
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.ediscovery.tagOperation",
  "createdDateTime": "2021-11-11T21:37:41.4396791Z",
  "completedDateTime": "2021-11-11T21:40:42.919Z",
  "percentProgress": 100,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "action": "applyTags",
  "id": "b1755016878c49ed875ce9246c30614d",
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "displayName": null,
      "userPrincipalName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpZQE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nfbZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGD4O.png)